# How to prepend CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX when its provided at build-time?

Tags: path, cmake, prefix

I have a few libraries that I build in succession.  Some depend on others.  For example:

`libfoo.so` depends on `libbar.so`

And, I don't want to have to deploy these things system-wide on the build machine.  In my cmake file I have something like the following:

```
find_library(FOO_LIB foo /usr/lib64 /usr/lib /usr/local/lib)
```

On the build machine I normally give it a `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` flag at compile-time.  Is there a way to do something like this:

```
find_library(FOO_LIB foo ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib /usr/lib64 /usr/lib /usr/local/lib)
```

if the flag is provided, but use the first version if it isn't provided?

*please forgive my noobish-ness with respect to cmake*

**[clarification]** Each library is built by a separate CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: If both libraries are built by the same cmakelists, you don't need a find_library call. Instead you can use target_link_libraries( foo  bar )

Answer (score 0):

If you have one cmake-project which include other cmake-projects (with your libraries and applications), you can use target names to link libraries: `target_link_libraries(app foo bar)`

If you build your libraries cmake project separately - it's not good way, I think, but you still have two options:

- deploy your libraries before build app;
- put already built libraries to third_party catalog and find it them (e.g. writing specific FindXXXX.cmake file which try to locate your libraries in third_party catalog first).